# notepad++ opengl auto-complete plugin

Tags: opengl, plugins, notepad++

I want to use notepad++ as text editor. So can anyone suggest me a plugin for notepad++ that enables auto-complete feature for typing openGL functions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any OpenGL autocomplete plugins for NotePad++. It's just a basic text editor. Switch to a full featured IDE to have that ability.

Comment: then can you tell me some IDE that have autocomplete support for openGL

Comment: I'm on a Mac and Xcode does OpenGL, GLU, GLUT, OpenGL ES very well. Not sure about Windows/Linux, but Eclipse seems to be a good bet [Setup GLUT on Eclipse](http://elleestcrimi.me/2010/10/06/setting-glut-eclipse-windows/)

Comment: Any IDE with autocomplete/Intellisense for C or C++ will support it for OpenGL, since it's no different than any other C header. That goes for OpenGL, ES, GLU, GLUT, GLEW, and the rest.